# Threads in Class Diagram (UML) 

Tags: uml

How do we show a thread is invoked and inturn invokes other threads in UML Diagram.This looks more like a WorkFlow. Is it possible to represent in UML

Answer (score 4):

[Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) should do the work.

Comment: Yes the thread behaviour can be shown in a sequence diagram but showing in a UML class diagram that a class launch a thread makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Yasin, Sequence Diagram might do the job.

[Activity Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) is another option that's well suited for showing workflow.  Parallelism, threads, synchronisation etc. are definitely one of the sweet spots and arguably easier to understand in an Activity Diagram than a Sequence Diagram.

hth.

Comment: Thanks @Yasin ,@sfinnie.Yes as pointed out both Sequence Diagram and Activity Diagram can help us to represent thread interaction. I started with Class diagram to represent a system .But as i came to threads class i was not sure if there was a way to represent it in Class diagram.Though Activity Diagram and Sequence Diagram are good ways to represent this flow, how do we represent this invoking mechanism in Class Diagram

Comment: Depends what you mean by "representing this invoking mechanism".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: We have composition to show that an object is destroyed if the parent is destroyed and aggregation to show that the object can live independently. Both of which have representation in Class diagram using diamond arrows.Though we can represent this using composition and aggregation to show the life cycle management of the thread being invoked is there any other representation for thread specifically

Comment: @Siva: not that I know of in a class diagram.  You can stereotype a class as <<active>> which implies it has its own thread of execution.  However I don't think that's really what you're looking for.  It's somewhat unusual to show relations among classes and threads - at least at the domain level.  How would you describe (in words) the relationship you're trying to model?  e.g. from a different example: `Each person may own many Dogs`.  How would you write a similar sentence combining your class + Thread?

Comment: You might find [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120859/uml-diagrams-of-multi-threaded-applications) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

UML is a language with a very structured syntax and semantics. 
See the UML specification at http://www.omg.org/spec/UML

To answer your question consider that in UML a Thread is an active class. 
The UML Class meta-class in fact owns a boolean attribute named isActive with the semantics you need. An active class owns a classifier behavior which is the behavior that will  be atuomatically executed, for each object, as soon as the class is instantiated. If the behavior is modeled by means of an activity or an interaction in which other active classes are instantiated (Create action) then this is semantically similar to a thread spawning other threads.